# Column in Tabularx is too wide

Tags: tables, tabularx

Please consider my minimal example. In my Tabularx table, the second column is wider than the rest of the columns. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} |p{2cm}|X*{32}{|c}| @{}}
        \hline
        This is an example:&
        1&
        2&
        3&
        4&
        5&
        6&
        7&
        8&
        9&
        10&
        11&
        12&
        13&
        14&
        15&
        16&
        17&
        18&
        19&
        20&
        21&
        22&
        23&
        24&
        25&
        26&
        27&
        28&
        29&
        30&
        31&
        32\\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have created a first column p of 2cm then a column X as large as possible and finally 32 columns c. Try this \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{2cm}|*{32}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}

Comment: You've set up a table with 34 columns, but you appear to be using only 33 of them. Did you maybe intend to write `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | *{32}{c|}}`, i.e., omit `|p{2cm}`?